# How to enable/disable buttons on the Excel ribbon via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Within an Excel add-in I'm developing, I make a call to an API and send over the users activation key. If the API recognises the key then it returns a token which means the user is authenticated. Once authenticated, I want to enable the buttons on my add-in's ribbon. So unless they're authorised, they don't get to use it.

My ribbon xml file looks like:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnRibbonLoad">

<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab id="CustomTab" getLabel="GetLabel" insertBeforeMso= "TabDeveloper">

<group id="GroupA" getVisible = "GetVisible" getLabel="GetLabel">
<button id="aButton01" getLabel="GetLabel" onAction="RunMacro"  getImage="GetImage" getSize="GetSize" getScreentip = "GetScreentip" getVisible = "GetVisible" getEnabled="GetEnabled"  />
</group>

<group id="GroupB" getVisible = "GetVisible" getLabel="GetLabel">
<button id="bButton01" getLabel="GetLabel" onAction="RunMacro"  getImage="GetImage" getSize="GetSize" getScreentip = "GetScreentip" getVisible = "GetVisible" getEnabled="GetEnabled" />
<button id="bButton02" getLabel="GetLabel" onAction="RunMacro"  getImage="GetImage" getSize="GetSize" getScreentip = "GetScreentip" getVisible = "GetVisible" getEnabled="GetEnabled" />
<button id="bButton03" getLabel="GetLabel" onAction="RunMacro"  getImage="GetImage" getSize="GetSize" getScreentip = "GetScreentip" getVisible = "GetVisible" getEnabled="GetEnabled" />
</group>

</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I assign various properties to the buttons via helper methods. An example of the `GetVisible` one:

```
Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef MakeVisible)
'PURPOSE: Show/Hide buttons based on how many you need (False = Hide/True = Show)

Select Case control.ID
  Case "GroupA": MakeVisible = True
  Case "aButton01": MakeVisible = True

  Case "GroupB": MakeVisible = True
  Case "bButton01": MakeVisible = True
  Case "bButton02": MakeVisible = True
  Case "bButton03": MakeVisible = True

End Select

End Sub
```

My `OnRibbonLoad` method is:

```
Dim MyRibbonUI As IRibbonUI

Private Sub OnRibbonLoad(ribbonUI As IRibbonUI)

    Dim Authenticate As New AuthenticationClass

    Set MyRibbonUI = ribbonUI

    ' Enable/Disable buttons based on authentication status
    If Authenticate.Authentify = False Then
        ' Lock the Ribbon
        Debug.Print ("Unauthorized!")
    Else
        ' Unlock the Ribbon
        Debug.Print ("Authorized!")
    End If

End Sub
```

I have tried creating a `GetEnabled` method which I could call `OnRibbonLoad` which would toggle the availability of the buttons but I cannot figure out how I would go about calling it:

```
Sub GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef MakeEnabled)

Select Case control.ID
  Case "GroupA": MakeEnabled = Enabled
  Case "aButton01": MakeEnabled = Enabled

  Case "GroupB": MakeEnabled = Enabled
  Case "bButton01": MakeEnabled = Enabled
  Case "bButton02": MakeEnabled = Enabled
  Case "bButton03": MakeEnabled = Enabled

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at Ribbon.Invalidate.

Comment: @DougGlancy...so helpful Doug.

Comment: Good! Invalidate isn't the name I would have chosen. It sounds sonegative :-)

Comment: @DougGlancy any idea how you can reference specific control ids?

Comment: There's an Invalidate for that too. RibbonControl, I think.